# Azure media services with .Net create transform gives conflicts error

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

**Problem:**

I am trying to upload a video to azure media services using azure functions and .Net core.In there I have created a function to create Transform. But that function is failing with giving me this error.

```
Exception occurred running the function.
Exception Data: Message- One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'); InnerException- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'
[2021-11-07T04:23:25.745Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.TransformsOperations.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(String resourceGroupName, String accountName, String transformName, IList`1 outputs, String description, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2021-11-07T04:23:25.751Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.TransformsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ITransformsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String accountName, String transformName, IList`1 outputs, String description, CancellationToken cancellationToken
```

This my getOrCreateTransformAsync function.

```
 public async Task<Transform> GetOrCreateTransformAsync(
            Dictionary<string, string> config, string transformName)
        {
            // Does a Transform already exist with the desired name? Assume that an existing Transform with the desired name
            // also uses the same recipe or Preset for processing content.
            IAzureMediaServicesClient client = await CreateMediaServicesClientAsync(config);
            bool createTransform = false;
            Transform transform = null;
            try
            {
                transform = client.Transforms.Get(
                   config.GetValueOrDefault("ResourceGroup"), config.GetValueOrDefault("AccountName"), transformName);
            }
            catch (ErrorResponseException ex) when (ex.Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                createTransform = true;
            }

            if (createTransform)
            {
                // You need to specify what you want it to produce as an output
                TransformOutput[] output = new TransformOutput[]
                {
            new TransformOutput
            {
                // The preset for the Transform is set to one of Media Services' built-in sample presets.
                // You can customize the encoding settings by changing this to use the "StandardEncoderPreset" class.
                Preset = new BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset()
                {
                    // This sample uses the built-in encoding preset for Adaptive Bitrate Streaming.
                    PresetName = EncoderNamedPreset.AdaptiveStreaming
                }
            }
                };

                // Create the Transform with the output defined above
                transform = await client.Transforms.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
                    config.GetValueOrDefault("ResourceGroup"), config.GetValueOrDefault("AccountName"), transformName, output);
            }
            return transform;
        }
```

This is my CreateMediaServiceClientAsync function

```
private async Task<IAzureMediaServicesClient> CreateMediaServicesClientAsync(Dictionary<string, string> config)
        {
            var credentials = await GetCredentialsAsync(config);

            return new AzureMediaServicesClient(credentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = config.GetValueOrDefault("SubscriptionId"),
            };
        }

 private async Task<ServiceClientCredentials> GetCredentialsAsync(Dictionary<string, string> config)
        {
            // Use ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync to get a token using a service principal with symmetric key
            var scopes = new[] { config.GetValueOrDefault("ArmAadAudience") + "/.default" };
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.GetValueOrDefault("AadClientId"))
       .WithClientSecret(config.GetValueOrDefault("AadSecret"))
       .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, config.GetValueOrDefault("AadTenantId"))
       .Build();

            var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                                                     .ExecuteAsync()
                                                     .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return new TokenCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
        }
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I tried a lot to find out a solution to this. But I was unable to do so.Thank you

Comment: Can you try by specifying `OnError` property of `TransformOutput` as `ContinueJob`? Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.transformoutput?view=azure-dotnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Gaurav-Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

As per the Transform Output Class Document try specifying the `OnError` property of `TransformOutput` as `ContinueJob`

Describes the properties of a `TransformOutput`, which are the rules to be applied while generating the desired output.

```
public class TransformOutput
```

[image]